# Portable VirtualBox with Ubuntu on two machines

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have VirtualBox Portable installed from [vbox.me](http://www.vbox.me/). I moved it on a USB drive and added a virtual Ubuntu.

It works fine on the computer I created it, but moving the usb drive to a different the Ubuntu does not start any more.

I already changed location descriptions in `<machine>.vbox` and the `VirtualBox.xml`. 
When pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> while starting the GRUB loader comes up, so I tried the recovery mode. Same here – startup freezes and nothing happens. Any hints for me?

Last to happen in log file:

```
00:00:54.986 Display::handleDisplayResize(): uScreenId = 0, pvVRAM=06aac000 w=640 h=480 bpp=32 

cbLine=0xA00, flags=0x1
00:01:06.361 Display::handleDisplayResize(): uScreenId = 0, pvVRAM=00000000 w=720 h=400 bpp=0 cbLine=0x0, flags=0x1
```

Comment: same happens if I export the machine on the AMD machine with Win7 64bit and trying to reimport on a Intel Win7 32bi .... ???